# Oracle 19c: Extract data (select) from XML (CLOB Type)

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle19c

I'm trying to extract data from a CLOB data field in xml.
But I'm not succeeding.

A part of XML file:

```
<tot type="5011">
    <eSl xmlns="http://www.dual.com">
        <evtCS Id="ID742">
            <ideEvt>
                <indAp>1</indAp>
            </ideEvt>
            <ideEmp>
                <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
                <nrInsc>99988877</nrInsc>
            </ideEmp>
            <infoCS>
                <ideEstab>
                    <nrInsc>99988877000111</nrInsc>
                </ideEstab>
                <ideEstab>
                    <nrInsc>99988877000222</nrInsc>
                </ideEstab>
            </infoCS>
        </evtCS>
    </eSl>
</tot>
```

Need to select values from  tag
I'm using XMLTYPE and EXTRACT, I also tried EXTRACTVALUE and it didn't work.

Comment: Which values are you trying to extract?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your RDBMS and its version.

Comment: Trying to extract a <nrInsc>

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get all useful pieces of information from the XML you provided using the query below. It utilizes `XMLTABLE` which can be useful when you have multiple of the same nodes (like `ideEstab` in your sample data) in the XML.

**Query**

```sql
WITH sample_data (some_xml) AS (SELECT EMPTY_CLOB () || '<tot type="5011">
    <eSl xmlns="http://www.dual.com">
        <evtCS Id="ID742">
            <ideEvt>
                <indAp>1</indAp>
            </ideEvt>
            <ideEmp>
                <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
                <nrInsc>99988877</nrInsc>
            </ideEmp>
            <infoCS>
                <ideEstab>
                    <nrInsc>99988877000111</nrInsc>
                </ideEstab>
                <ideEstab>
                    <nrInsc>99988877000222</nrInsc>
                </ideEstab>
            </infoCS>
        </evtCS>
    </eSl>
</tot>' FROM DUAL)
       SELECT x.tot_type,
              x.evtcs_id,
              x.indap,
              x.tpinsc,
              x.emp_nrinsc,
              c.cs_nrinsc
         FROM sample_data
              CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE (xmlnamespaces ('http://www.dual.com' AS "d"),
                                   '/'
                                   PASSING xmltype (some_xml)
                                   COLUMNS tot_type      NUMBER PATH '/tot/@type',
                                           evtcs_id      VARCHAR2 (100) PATH '/tot/d:eSl/d:evtCS/@Id',
                                           indap         NUMBER PATH '/tot/d:eSl/d:evtCS/d:ideEvt/d:indAp',
                                           tpinsc        NUMBER PATH '/tot/d:eSl/d:evtCS/d:ideEmp/d:tpInsc',
                                           emp_nrinsc    NUMBER PATH '/tot/d:eSl/d:evtCS/d:ideEmp/d:nrInsc',
                                           infocs_xml    XMLTYPE PATH '/tot/d:eSl/d:evtCS/d:infoCS') x
              CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE (xmlnamespaces ('http://www.dual.com' AS "d"),
                                   '/d:infoCS/d:ideEstab'
                                   PASSING infocs_xml
                                   COLUMNS cs_nrinsc     NUMBER PATH '/d:ideEstab/d:nrInsc') c;
```

**Output**

```
   TOT_TYPE EVTCS_ID       INDAP    TPINSC    EMP_NRINSC         CS_NRINSC
___________ ___________ ________ _________ _____________ _________________
       5011 ID742              1         1      99988877    99988877000111
       5011 ID742              1         1      99988877    99988877000222
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

Everything is standard, just the default namespace should be taken care of.

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/V21qtucp)

**SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE HOLDS_XML
        (xml_col CLOB);

INSERT INTO HOLDS_XML (xml_col)
VALUES ('<tot type="5011">
    <eSl xmlns="http://www.dual.com">
        <evtCS Id="ID742">
            <ideEvt>
                <indAp>1</indAp>
            </ideEvt>
            <ideEmp>
                <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
                <nrInsc>99988877</nrInsc>
            </ideEmp>
            <infoCS>
                <ideEstab>
                    <nrInsc>99988877000111</nrInsc>
                </ideEstab>
                <ideEstab>
                    <nrInsc>99988877000222</nrInsc>
                </ideEstab>
            </infoCS>
        </evtCS>
    </eSl>
</tot>');

SELECT y.*
      FROM HOLDS_XML,
           XMLTABLE (xmlnamespaces('http://www.dual.com' as "ns1"),
           '/tot/ns1:eSl/ns1:evtCS' 
           PASSING XMLTYPE(xml_col)
COLUMNS Id VARCHAR2(500) PATH '@Id',
      indAp INTEGER PATH 'ns1:ideEvt/ns1:indAp',
      tpInsc INTEGER PATH 'ns1:ideEmp/ns1:tpInsc') y;
```

**Output**

| ID | INDAP | TPINSC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID742 | 1 | 1 |